# Fazer calculo com o resultado do select

Tags: sql, matemática

Como posso fazer um calculo no select abaixo?
Fiz as somas das quantidades e dos valores, agora preciso pegar essas somas e fazer um saldo.

Seria assim:

> qtd_tipo_0 - qtd_tipo_1 - qtd_tipo_2

e

> total_tipo_0 - total_tipo_1 - total_tipo_2

```
SELECT 
cat.id, 
cat.nome, 
SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 0, mov.qtd, 0 ) ) AS qtd_tipo_0, 
SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 0, mov.total, 0 ) ) AS total_tipo_0, 
SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 1, mov.qtd, 0 ) ) AS qtd_tipo_1, 
SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 1, mov.total, 0 ) ) AS total_tipo_1, 
SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 2, mov.qtd, 0 ) ) AS qtd_tipo_2, 
SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 2, mov.total, 0 ) ) AS total_tipo_2 
FROM lc_movimento AS mov 
INNER JOIN lc_cat AS cat 
ON cat.id = mov.cat 
GROUP BY cat.nome ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

Transforme em uma `subquery` :

```
SELECT
    (qtd_tipo_0 + qtd_tipo_1 + qtd_tipo_2) as qtdTotal,
    (total_tipo_0 + total_tipo_1 + total_tipo_2) as total,
    (total_tipo_0 + total_tipo_1 + total_tipo_2) / (qtd_tipo_0 + qtd_tipo_1 + qtd_tipo_2) as media,
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        cat.id, 
        cat.nome, 
        SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 0, mov.qtd, 0 ) ) AS qtd_tipo_0, 
        SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 0, mov.total, 0 ) ) AS total_tipo_0, 
        SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 1, mov.qtd, 0 ) ) AS qtd_tipo_1, 
        SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 1, mov.total, 0 ) ) AS total_tipo_1, 
        SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 2, mov.qtd, 0 ) ) AS qtd_tipo_2, 
        SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 2, mov.total, 0 ) ) AS total_tipo_2 
    FROM
        lc_movimento AS mov 
        INNER JOIN lc_cat AS cat ON cat.id = mov.cat 
    GROUP BY 
        cat.nome ASC
) as somatorios
```

#### Adendo

Se quiser ainda pode gerar uma `subquery` da `subquery`

```
SELECT
    vlTotal / qtdTotal as media,
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        (qtd_tipo_0 + qtd_tipo_1 + qtd_tipo_2) as qtdTotal,
        (total_tipo_0 + total_tipo_1 + total_tipo_2) as vlTotal,
        *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            cat.id, 
            cat.nome, 
            SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 0, mov.qtd, 0 ) ) AS qtd_tipo_0, 
            SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 0, mov.total, 0 ) ) AS total_tipo_0, 
            SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 1, mov.qtd, 0 ) ) AS qtd_tipo_1, 
            SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 1, mov.total, 0 ) ) AS total_tipo_1, 
            SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 2, mov.qtd, 0 ) ) AS qtd_tipo_2, 
            SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 2, mov.total, 0 ) ) AS total_tipo_2 
        FROM
            lc_movimento AS mov 
            INNER JOIN lc_cat AS cat ON cat.id = mov.cat 
        GROUP BY 
            cat.nome ASC
    ) as somatorio_unicos
) somatorio_geral
```

Comment: Opa, mas assim ele perde as colunas de quantidade e de valores, eu preciso dessa colunas no relatório e incluir as colunas de saldos que é a conta desses resultados

Comment: @user45885 editei, adicionando o `*` para retornar os demais campos.

Comment: da erro #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM ( SELECT cat.id , cat.nome , SUM( IF( mov.tipo = 0 , mov.qtd , 0 ) ' at line 1